# Find impulse provided by the stopping object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, collision

I have tried to understand this problem, but I'm still struggling with it.

a 27g bullet hits a piece of wood and goes in 8.6 cm. if the bullet stopped in 0.44ms. what impulse did the wood provide?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please note that we don't do worked examples here. Do you have a specific question about a physics concept?

Answer (score 1):

As the person commented on your post, we don't work homework problems like this for you. However, I can briefly explain what impulse is. The definition of impulse is $J = \int^{t_1}_{t_0} F(t) dt = (t_1-t_0)F_{avg} = \int^{t_1}_{t_0} \frac{dp}{dt}dt = p(t_1) - p(t_0)$ by mean value theorem and the integral theorem of calculus respectively. So you need to find either the average force applied to the bullet, or the momentum before it entered the wood. I'll leave it up to you to determine which is appropriate, as that is the point of this problem.